# Python requests function

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I've got a strange problem with requests. Currently I am working on web-scraping problem to gather data about malicious webpages from open-source internet tools. I've got a file where potentially malicious websites are stored I want to check the reputation of that websites on Virus-total. I am trying to use api calls. Everything works as It was described in Api docs untill I decided to contactenate link to api call, here is example.

```
 domain_check=f'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/domain/report?apikey=<YOUR_API_KEY>&domain={lines}'
response_2=requests.get(domain_check)
print(response_2.text)
```

In this code value of lines changes with every loop to domain that i want to check(values are stored in text file). The strange thing is that if i type it manually it work's as it should.
I've been using requests module for a while and this is the first time when I am facing that kind of probelm have you ever had that issue?

Comment: Can you provide a sample value for the variable `line`?

Comment: Sample is

    lines=ui.threatstream.com
    So after concatenation it result's in https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/domain/report?apikey=45078e7e54f452c0192fdgs45f75effc2a0a1390edb8b4a75a346e4768d04e7&domain=ui.threatstream.com

When I search for that url via browser it work as it should(if any of you  do this it will not work because I've changed apikey in this link before posting).
I thought that it's because of whitespace so I use strip to delete additional whitespaces, but It didn't help as well.